# Expo SDK 50 Firebase Cloud Messaging Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, mern

I successfully implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with Expo SDK 48 without any issues.
However, upon upgrading to Expo SDK 50, I encountered an error while using FCM.

I want to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with Expo SDK 50.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRfFv.png)

[app.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjNvB.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeOqP.png)

[package.json continued](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQdQG.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apsfu.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because you are trying to use firebase/messaging in expo go app. Expo go app does not support firebase/messaging as of now. You will need to test or use it in either expo-dev-client or in actual apk. For further information regarding expo-dev-client follow steps provided in https://docs.expo.dev/develop/development-builds/create-a-build/

Comment:  Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew"

i got this error when iam trying to make expo build, using eas build --profile development --platform android. so how can i test it in expo-dev-client?

Comment: In that case follow below steps properly.

1. Make sure to have eas account and link with project by eas build:configure 
2. npx expo install expo-dev-client
3. eas build --profile development --platform android /
eas build --profile development-simulator --platform ios --clear-cache
4. Install the generated build in your device
5. in project terminal run command npx expo start --dev-client 6. Enter the generated url in the enter url TextInput of your app

THIS CAN BE USED FOR TESTING/DEVELOPMENT SUCH AS IN APP PDF READER.
And that's it!!!!

Comment: Yes Dev build is installed, Now after running app in Dev build, i got this error:  possible unhandled promise rejection (id: o): Error: Missing or invalid FirebaseOptions property 'apikey'.

Comment: Have you made sure to add your google-services.json in your project which you would get from your firebase console of your project? also, add the path of google-services.json to your app.json.